# Android - Login authentication using wsdl webservice using ksoap2

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services

I have created the `loginform` in android and that checks the authenticate on server, but it will not give me the output and I don't know which error is occurred!!

My Android activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.webapp.org";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.0.2:8080/WebApp2/services/SearchData?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.webapp.org/getSearchData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "getSearchData";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            loginAction();              
        }
    });
}

private void loginAction(){
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        result.setText(response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();          
    }
   }
```

Android `manifest.xml` file: i have given the permission of `manifest.xml`

Please Help..!!

Comment: Never make a HTTP call in the main thread.

Comment: so now what can i use instead of HTTP call??

Comment: Use async task to do network operations.

Comment: Here is a very nice tutorial on soap parsing http://android.programmerguru.com/android-webservice-example/

Comment: I have posted the same as an answer, you can accept the same.

Answer (score 2):

Never make a HTTP request/Network call in the main thread, Always use Asynctask to do longer operations in background so that it may not halt the UI thread.

A very nice tutorial and step by step guide is available in this [tutorial](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-webservice-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you does not use direct call of any web related action....

You first call background thread and call web related action... .

Refer this code:

Blockquote

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

         AddReviewAsyncTask  call  = new AddReviewAsyncTask ();

         call.execute();

    }
});




private class AddReviewAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{

int responce;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     loginAction(); 
    return null;


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

}
```